# Fill screen except space in Java

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d

I'm trying to render fog of war with the `Graphics2D` object in Java.  Currently, I'm rendering like this.

```
// Color the screen black
Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 200);
graphics.setColor(color);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, entity.getWorld().getGame().getWidth(), entity.getWorld().getGame().getHeight());
// Make a rectangle around the Entity that is normal
color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
graphics.setColor(color);
PositionComponent2D data = (PositionComponent2D) entity.getComponent("pos");
Vector2D pos = data.getAABB().getPosition();
graphics.fillRect((int) pos.getX() - 20, (int) pos.getY() - 20, 40, 40);
```

And it gives the effect I'm looking for, except the second portion of the code doesn't work.  Is there any way that I can render everywhere on the screen except for near the player to give a fog-of-war effect?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a [composite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html) for your second drawing call...something like this (disclaimer: I haven't tried to run this code, but this ought to be a starting point):

```
// Color the screen black
Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 200);
graphics.setColor(color);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, entity.getWorld().getGame().getWidth(), entity.getWorld().getGame().getHeight());
// Make a rectangle around the Entity that is normal
Composite oldComposite = graphics.getComposite();
graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.CLEAR);
PositionComponent2D data = (PositionComponent2D) entity.getComponent("pos");
Vector2D pos = data.getAABB().getPosition();
graphics.fillRect((int) pos.getX() - 20, (int) pos.getY() - 20, 40, 40);
graphics.setComposite(oldComposite);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I tried your answer, and looking at the docs it's really not what I want. Right now there's just a white circle when the player should be.

Comment: I'd need more of your code to help troubleshoot that - but it sounds like what you may need to do is create a BufferedImage that's your "fog of war" plane, use the above code to fill your BufferedImage with a "black square with a hole around the player", then use Graphics2D.drawImage.